# How to show custom Microsoft 365 app in Outlook on the web?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams, microsoft365

We have build Microsoft teams app that works across m365/Outloook/Teams. This app appears inside teams and  m365, but not in Outlook. Is there a way to put our custom app inside left apps bar in Outlook OWA?

[image: Apps bar]

I'm new to microsoft admin center and I'm trying to figure out what configuration would help me with my problem, but I haven't found anything related yet.

Comment: Could you please verify whether required Client Id values are added in [Authorized client applications section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-personal-tab?tabs=manifest-teams-toolkit#update-azure-ad-app-registration-for-sso) of your app in Azure? Also please make sure you have enabled Targeted release for everyone on `Admin Center > Org settings > Organization profile`

Comment: I've  verified  Cliend Id  values, Outlook is present here. I enabled Targeted release for everyone and it worked! Can you please explain why it works like this?

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. As asked, enabling Targeted release is pre-requisite as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/prerequisites) in order to preview Teams apps running in Outlook and Microsoft 365 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was not enabling Targeted release as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/prerequisites#enroll-your-developer-tenant-for-microsoft-365-targeted-releases-optional).